# Modify variable of parent controller inside child controller AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have my body controlled by a `MainController`. In the body, I have another nested controller. In my `index.html`, I have a `div` element controlled by the nested controller:

*index.html*

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-controller="LoginController" ng-hide="isLoggedIn"></div>
  <div class="navbar" ng-hide="!isLoggedIn">
    <!-- A form which calls login() function inside LoginController -->
  </div>
</body>
```

*MainController:*

```
angular.module('DemoApp')
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
}]);
```

*LoginController*

```
angular.module('DemoApp')
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.login = function () {
       if($scope.loginCredentials.username === 'username' && $scope.loginCredentials.password === 'password') {
            $scope.parent.isLoggedIn = true; /* here, how to modify this variable */
            $location.path('/home');
        }
   };
}]);
```

All I want to do is change the variables of `MainController`, which is `isLoggedIn`, from my nested controllers. I used `$scope.parent`, but it shows `unknow provider parent`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Use  $localStorage to store isLoggedIn.  and get it from $localStorage when needed. This data is available until you manually clear the key.

Comment: @SharanDeSilva thanks, I'll use that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$parent` to get the parent controller scope, then various methods and properties can be accessed.

```
$scope.$parent.isLoggedIn = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, if I go on home page again, I need to set that variable to false. How to do that?